# SQL Max with Group By Sub Queries

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table with insurance benefits, and years they were given.  I would like to find the benefits with the most counts per year.

I am using sqlite3 in python 3.

My first query is

```
SELECT COUNT(Benefitname) AS BenCount, BusinessYear
FROM BenefitsCostSharing
GROUP BY Benefitname
```

This gives me a table with benefits counts and the year.
I put this first query into a sub query trying to find the most counts by year with the following code:

```
SELECT MAX(BenCount), BusinessYear 
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(Benefitname) AS BenCount, BusinessYear
      FROM BenefitsCostSharing
      GROUP BY Benefitname
     )
GROUP BY BusinessYear;
```

This query gives me the following maxes for each year:

2014-77377

2015-3049

2016-644

I know the max count for years 2015 and 2016 are not right.  But I don't know why it isn't working.

My data is from https://www.kaggle.com/hhs/health-insurance-marketplace

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, I don't think you even need to have the subquery, you can simply do: `select max(count(benefitname)), BusinessYear from BenefitsCostSharing group by BusinessYear`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find the benefits with the most counts per year.

Your query doesn't show the benefits, so something seems off.  But to answer this question, use window functions:

```
SELECT yb.*
FROM (SELECT BusinessYear, Benefitname, COUNT(*) AS BenCount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BusinessYear ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BenefitsCostSharing
      GROUP BY Benefitname
     ) yb
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Youll need to group by year and benefit name and then join:

```
SELECT year, name
FROM (SELECT BusinessYear as year, Benefitname as name, COUNT(*),
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BusinessYear ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as rn
      FROM BenefitsCostSharing
      GROUP BY BusinessYear, Benefitname
     ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```